# Why isn't TrayIcon receiving mouse events?

Tags: java

I am trying to fix a broken tray icon in an open source project. I have almost no experience with GUIs in Java, I am lost. I would appreciate any tips.

I am testing it in KDE, tray icon is shown and changes status (image) correctly, but title is wrong (always JEmbeddedFrame, despite the fact method is called with right string) and no click events are fired.

```
        trayIcon.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            // this is never called :(
            public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent event) { 
                if (!mainFrame.isVisible()) {
                    mainFrame.setVisible(true);
                }

                mainFrame.setState(JFrame.NORMAL);
                mainFrame.requestFocus();
            }

        });
```

I even stepped into `TrayIcon` class to find that only mouse enter/leave events are begin fired, but never press, release or click. Is this a bug in JRE or am I missing something?

The question is: **How to fix the tray icon to receive mouse events (mainly click one) in KDE?**

My Java version is `Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)` and KDE is 5.5.5 (Kubuntu LTS).

Code: https://github.com/mnn/baralga/blob/master/baralga-core/src/main/java/org/remast/baralga/gui/TrayIcon.java#L68

Answer (score 0):

[Doc of JDK7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/TrayIcon.html#addMouseListener%28java.awt.event.MouseListener%29) says that it does not support it & already tested by me in JDK8, still not working. But [JDK11](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/TrayIcon.html#addMouseMotionListener(java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener)) does not explicitly say something like this.

Comment: Maybe in java 7, which is the Java doc you linked, but in more modern versions [like 11](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/TrayIcon.html#addMouseMotionListener(java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener)) it no longer says that.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas haven't tested it there unfortunately, in JDK8 it still doesn't work.

Comment: Probably should put that information in your answer. Right now it just says "it doesn't work" but that is specific to certain versions.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas you are right, thanks for the comment.